# Result of 'Rasterize' shows only "0" data

Tags: qgis, gdal-rasterize

I have point shapefile "TAEBAEK".
And i want convert it to raster.

Rasterize works well.
but result show only "0" data.

I thought result shows "0" and "1" data.
(the cell, containing the point, show "1". And the others show "0")

help me~

[image]